# Cannot remove replicated towns. Should it be a query issue?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a problem with displaying the towns in select tag. They are displayed in this way: [image]

As you can see, there are towns like **Berlin** which are duplicated. Also, I display them in dropdown list with the foolowing block of code:

```
<select id="veneue_finder_city_select" name="city_id">
                                <option value="">Any</option>
                                <?php
                                if( !empty($state_id) ) {

                                    $states = array();
                                    $cities = $wpdb->get_results( "select ID, post_title from $wpdb->posts where post_type = 'place' and post_parent = $state_id", ARRAY_A );

                                    foreach( $cities as $city ):
                                    ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $city['ID']; ?>" <?php selected($city['ID'], $city_id) ?>><?php echo $city['post_title']; ?></option>
                                    <?php endforeach;
                                }?>
                            </select>
```

I've already tried to use **Distinct**  type in the query, but without success. Should it be something else ? This is my **stade_id**

```
$state_id = isset( $_GET['state_id'] ) ? $_GET['state_id'] : '';
```

Comment: have you tried using `DISTINCT post_title` ?

Comment: The more appropriate question would be: Why do you have multiple **Berlin** in your database? Is your data flawed? I'd suggest fixing that instead of hotfixing your code.

Comment: But im not familiar  with wordpress db and can't find where're the towns. It's not only Berlin (which is duplicated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one thing make the result to unique array with the help of this function.

```
function unique_array($array)
{
  $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));

  foreach ($result as $key => $value)
  {
    if ( is_array($value) )
    {
      $result[$key] = $this->unique_array($value);
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Add this function to your code then call it after getting the result of city,just like this

```
$cities=$this->unique_array($cities);
```

It will give you the required unique array which can solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

there is query issue you can use

```
 `select ID, post_title from $wpdb->posts where post_type = 'place' and post_parent = $state_id GROUP BY post_title`
```